# Oracle select statement to show matching columns in two tables ? No data just the column names that exist in both the tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, database-metadata

How can i show all the columns which are similar in two tables in oracle db ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want something like this.

```
select t1.column_name 
  from all_tab_columns t1
 where t1.owner = <<table1 owner>>
   and t1.table_name = <<table1 name>>
intersect
select t2.column_name 
  from all_tab_columns t2
 where t2.owner = <<table1 owner>>
   and t2.table_name = <<table1 name>>
```

You could write it as a `join` or as an `exists` as well if you'd rather.  But `intersect` makes more sense to me from a readability perspective.  You could use `dba_tab_columns` or `user_tab_columns` rather than `all_tab_columns` depending on what privileges you have in the database, whether you know the tables are in your current schema, etc.

Comment: Hi Justin, the above script throws an Invalid Identifier error at t1.owner. Any suggestions ? Both tables are in same schema and all i did was adding ODB to t1.owner = 'odb' and t1.table_name = 'xyz'.

Comment: @sree - Sorry, brain fart.  Referenced the wrong table.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is aggregation:

```
select atc.column_name,
       (case when count(*) = 2 then 'Both'
             when min((atc.owner) = :owner1 and min(atc.table_name) = :table1
             then 'Table1 only'
             else 'Table2 only'
        end) 
from all_tab_columns atc
where (atc.owner = :owner1 and atc.table_name = :table1) or
      (atc.owner = :owner2 and atc.table_name = :table2) 
group by atc.column_name;
```

The advantage to this approach is that it easily generalizes to showing all columns:

```
select atc.column_name 
from all_tab_columns atc
where (atc.owner = :owner1 and atc.table_name = :table1) or
      (atc.owner = :owner2 and atc.table_name = :table2) 
group by atc.column_name
having count(*) = 2;
```